# Function equivalence

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

Let's say I have two functions, f(x) and g(x) that always produce the same output with any given x.

Is saying that f(x)=g(x) and solving the equations until I end up proving that x=x enough to show that they are equivalent?

Or do I have to to prove that for every possible x that f(x) = g(x), which is impossible since x could be any number?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no proving $x=x$. By the symmetry property of $=$ this is guaranteed. If you want to show that $f(x)=g(x)$ for all values $x$ in a common domain, then you would simply show equality of $f(x)=g(x)$ holds for an arbitrary $x$ in that domain. Do you have a particular $f$ and $g$ in mind?

Comment: Not really, just trying to understand what is appropriate generally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say it would be better to manipulate $f(x)$ until you obtain $g(x)$ or vice versa.

Bear in mind that you are looking for equivalence between the two functions, not equality.  It is summed up perfectly on purplemath.

"You can work on both sides together for a regular equation, because you're trying to find where the equation is true. When you are working with an identity, if you work on both sides and work down to where the sides are equal, you will only have shown that, if the starting equation is true, then you can arrive at another true equation. But you won't have proved, logically, that the original equation was actually true."